# DISCO_STM32L072: Device Registration PIN from Murata module

Tags: stm32, lora, lorawan

I'm using the Discovery Kit B-L072Z-LRWAN with the expansion package from ST (I-CUBE-LRWAN), but I need to get the Device Registration PIN from the Murata ([manual](https://wireless.murata.com/pub/RFM/data/SoftwareModem_Ref.pdf)) module in order to register the device in my LoRa-Cloud account.

I am aware that the manual describes how to do that via UART, but I tried everything and all the baudrates and I couldn't get any response from the board (I used minicom and connected to a USB-TTL converter)

Any help is more than welcome!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I still couldn't manage to get the device registration number, but I've done a few things (like develop a new UART application for an external processor as the manual suggests) and it seems that the firmware won't respond properly to any command. I've contacted the support and apparently it hasn't been put into extensive testing (as nobody had required this kind of support before) so they needed to investigate that a bit further.

Comment: Did you see my answer? Did it help you in any way?

Comment: I just did! And this number is not the DevEUI so it didn't help much. As I said, I talked to the manufacturer (Murata) and they said they were still developing this module so apparently there's no way to register Murata devices yet to LoRa Cloud

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong manual for that chip and software. The linked manual is for some Semtech implementation. You are using the [Murata CMWX1ZZABZ-xxx](https://wireless.murata.com/type-abz-078.html) software by ST (being the I-CUBE-LRWAN). (the numbers at the end of the part number differentiate between the STM32 microcontroller 78/91 which doesn't impact functionality.)

I don't directly know what "Device Registration PIN" means but I can guess that you are looking foor the DevEui of the device.

There are two options for the DevEui. One is the one calculated by the I-CUBE-LRWAN and is derived from the internal registers of the CMX1ZZABZ using `HW_GetUniqueId`. The other option is to set it using the following defines:

```
/*!
 * When set to 1 DevEui is LORAWAN_DEVICE_EUI
 * When set to 0 DevEui is automatically generated by calling
 *         BoardGetUniqueId function
 */
#define STATIC_DEVICE_EUI                                  0

/*!
 * Mote device IEEE EUI (big endian)
 *
 * \remark see STATIC_DEVICE_EUI comments
 */
#define LORAWAN_DEVICE_EUI                                 { IEEE_OUI, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 }
```

These are found in the `commisioning.h:106-118` file.

---

The implementation of the hardware derived DevEui is found inside `mlm32l0xx_hw.c:275-290`

```
/**
  * @brief This function return a unique ID
  * @param unique ID
  * @retval none
  */
void HW_GetUniqueId(uint8_t *id)
{
  id[7] = ((*(uint32_t *)ID1) + (*(uint32_t *)ID3)) >> 24;
  id[6] = ((*(uint32_t *)ID1) + (*(uint32_t *)ID3)) >> 16;
  id[5] = ((*(uint32_t *)ID1) + (*(uint32_t *)ID3)) >> 8;
  id[4] = ((*(uint32_t *)ID1) + (*(uint32_t *)ID3));
  id[3] = ((*(uint32_t *)ID2)) >> 24;
  id[2] = ((*(uint32_t *)ID2)) >> 16;
  id[1] = ((*(uint32_t *)ID2)) >> 8;
  id[0] = ((*(uint32_t *)ID2));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I was looking for. This device registration PIN is the same required here https://www.loracloud.com/documentation/join_service?url=quickstart.html to register a device on LoRa Cloud. It is very different from the DevEUI.